# Creating a table in google sheets for use with table formulas

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a google sheet with formulas that go by the cell in the previous row (e.g. `=IF(D12=FALSE,E11,E11+1)`.  When I insert a new row, the formula doesn't copy into the new row.

I was looking to create a table like you could in excel so that you could write formulas like `=[@[header]]` and when you inserted a new row, this carried into the new row.

Does anyone know how you can either create an array formula for the two below formulas, or how to format as table so you can define the `=[@[header]]` functions?

Two formulas that could be written as array:

For my sheet this one is inserted in cell E2: `=IF(D2=FALSE,E1,E1+1)`

This formula is in F2: `=IF(E1=E2,"",E2)`  - both continue for the entire column.

Answer (score 0):

for first use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D1000=FALSE, E1:E999, E1:E999+1))
```

and the second:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E1:E999=E2:E1000,,E2:E1000))
```

if you want it with header then:

```
={"header title"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E1:E999=E2:E1000,,E2:E1000))}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

For adding headers to your formulas using also `ARRAYFORMULA` just wrap the whole thing with `{}`. Note that in the second formula I have written `E3` instead of `E2` as `E2` would have the title of its formula.

These are the formulas to be used in your specific scenario:

For `E2` :

`={"title 1";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2=FALSE, E1, E1+1))}`

and for `F2` :

`={"title 2"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E1=E3, "", E3))}`

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)